# Is it ok to say "I had a question", when you in fact mean "I was asked a question"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, idioms

In an English teaching video, **the teacher** who is a native British English speaker answers the **questions from the learners**. And he says:

**"I had a question".** And he starts to say what the question is and tries to answer the question, which was asked by one of learners.

I found this sentence unusual, because I thought **"I had a question"** means almost the same as **"I have a question"**, only the past form of it. In other words, the sentence should mean **"I am the one who has the question"**. But the teacher used this sentence to refer to a question which he received from a learner, not his own question.

So, I got confused. Is "**I had a question**" not just the past version of **"I have a question"**?

or does "**I had a question"** have 2 meanings:

1-past tense of **"I have a question".**

2-another way of saying **"I have a received a question from somebody else to be answered by me.**

Thanks,

For those who wants to hear the sentence, the video is on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQBr6HnG1QI

Comment: Either tense can be used when stating something like that. When there is an audience, asking questions of a person, they might use either.

Comment: What do you think **I have a question** means?

Comment: Lucian, as far as I know, "I have a question" means "I have a question on my mind. The question is mine, not somebody else's". If I want to answer a question which somebody else asked me, I can't say "I have a question", can I?

Comment: Yes, you can! It can mean either I have received a question from the audience and now I'm going to answer it, or I'm going to address you [the audience] a question. Remember: context is everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has two meanings, you are right.

From the provided context, it is quite obvious that the teacher used the second (2) meaning; saying:

> I had a question.

as a mental "shortcut"; an implicit way of saying:

> I had been asked a question.

The other meaning: past tense version of "I have a question", makes no sense in this context because it would imply that the teacher had a question in the past, but no longer has a question in the present (because it had been already answered).